# ANGULAR 6 http get JSON

Tags: json, angular, http, get

I am having trouble getting information from certain json file.

**case 1 (works):**

service:

```
private xmlToJson: string = 'https://rss2json.com/api.json?rss_url=';

getImg(Url: string) {
return this.http.get(this.xmlToJson + Url);
}
```

component:

```
private url='https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne';

public images: any = [];

this.imgDataService.getImg(this.url)
  .subscribe(data => this.images = data);
```

HTML:

```
<h1>{{images.feed.title}}</h1>
```

**case 2 (does not work):**

service:

```
getImg(Url: string) {
return this.http.get(Url);
}
```

component:

```
private url = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&nojsoncallback=1';

public images: any = [];

this.imgDataService.getImg(this.url)
  .subscribe(data => this.images = data);
```

HTML:

```
<h1>{{images.title}}</h1>
```

Any idea why case 2 doesn't work? I ran both JSONs here: https://jsonlint.com/ and they came out valid.

Comment: change method signature and try getImg(Url: string): Observable<any>

Comment: Can you show json response returned by both the methods? And also in first case you have written `images.feed.title` and in second its just `images.title`.

Comment: @AmitChigadani that's because json 1 starts like this: 
{
"status": "ok"
"feed": {
"url": "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne"
"title": "Uploads from everyone"
"link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/"
"author": ""
"description": ""
"image": "https://s.yimg.com/pw/images/buddyicon.gif"
}...

while json 2 starts like this:

{
  "title": "Uploads from everyone",
  "link": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/",
  "description": "",
  "modified": "2018-10-11T11:52:18Z",
  "generator": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com",
  "items": [...

Comment: I can't write here clearly so you can just compare between those 2 links:
1. https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.flickr.com%2Fservices%2Ffeeds%2Fphotos_public.gne

  2.  https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&nojsoncallback=1

Comment: You can add those response in your question itself. That would be more clear to everyone.

Comment: And what error do you get for second case? Can you show that?

Comment: It is clear if you look at the 'url' and 'xmlToJson' properties. when i console.log image in the second case it is empty, and the <img> is broke

Comment: Your second case seems valid. In what way does it not work? Is the value blank, or is there an error message in your Chrome Dev Tools console?

Comment: @CobusKruger in the second case images value is blank. it seems the second case url some how doesnt retrieve a valid json (but if I copy the text inside to a new json file and call that file it works. I don't want to do that because the data their suppose to get updated).

Comment: @YardenA To quickly see exactly what you get back, change this: `this.imgDataService.getImg(this.url).subscribe(data => {console.log(data);});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) error.

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d4jpfk) showing the two calls and what is returned from the server. The call for the Flickr URL fails because the Flickr API doesn't (at least on this service) return headers for Access-Control-Allow-Origin to enable public access.

Ironically, you'll be able to call the web service from any code that is **not** running in a web browser.

Since you probably won't be able to convince them otherwise (others have tried), I would suggest you give up on Flickr.

A final note: You would be able to see the error if you opened your browser's developer tools and checked the console. That should be your first stop for any weird behaviour you encounter in web development.

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know why the data isn't getting updated when I use this tool? https://rss2json.com/#rss_url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.flickr.com%2Fservices%2Ffeeds%2Fphotos_public.gne
this is what I use in case 1, and if it could give me updated data from the flickr url (because the data does get updated when I refresh only the flickr link itself without this tool), it will be good enough for what I need.

Comment: The tool caches the result of the feed for one hour. This is a limitation of their free product. See https://rss2json.com/plans.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `public images: any = []`
to `public images: any = {}`

Images data isn't an array.

Comment: doesn't work. and in any case it doesn't explain why case 1 works

Comment: This wont matter. When the object is assigned to it, the type of `images` is no longer an array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `this.imgDataService.getImg(this.url)` type `this.imgDataService.getImg(this.url2)`

Comment: this was just a mistake in the question. still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this approach if you know what kind of json response is expected then probably you can create class like
Example:

```
export class ImageModel{

name:string;
title:string;
src:string;
}
```

where name,title and src are json keys
then in you can do:

```
constructor(private httpService:HttpService){}

getImg(Url: string) {
return this.httpService.get<ImageModel>(

(image:ImageModel) => {return image}
}
```

new HttpService should automatically map your json data to the javascript class/Interface
and then you can read the image to get the json data.